# defining all columns in django values just to get foreign key value

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am working on a Django app and I have a model containing about 60 columns with few ForeignKeys

For e.g.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # and many more rows
```

I need to show all data in DataTable.

```
Company.objects.all().values()
```

To get the username from `user` column, I need to call it as

```
Company.objects.all().values('user__username')
```

But this doesn't makes sense to me,
Just to get the username, I will have to define all columns of Company model

```
Company.objects.all().values('name', 'city', 'address', 'user__username')
```

I was already getting `'name', 'city', 'address'` with `.values()` But to get `username`, I have to define them explicitly.

This is okay with small models, but this approach becomes tidious and error-prone with bigger models.

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this that I dont know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I find it strange to use `.values(..)` in the first place, since this will remove the "model layer" from the data.

Comment: I am using DataTables to show the data, and for that reason, I need to pass JSON object, which `.values()` returns

Comment: no it is a popular misconception that this is a JSON object, this is a *Python dictionary*, and of course you can JSON serialize that dictionary then, but that is irrelevant here. It will for example for a `ForeignKey` not return an object, but simply the target primary key. To JSON serialize something, you typically use the serializers of the DRF framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ or Django's serialization framework https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/

Comment: yeah! wrong words... the return of `.values()` is Python Dictionary, but I was saying in the context of jQuery's Datatables. I need to pass data in `{key: value}` format, I am already halfway through it, but having a problem getting values from the Foreign key which returns only integer value